# Working with JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
class MyClass {
    public String name;
}

class MyTableRow {
    public MyClass data;
    public boolean isChecked = false;

    public MyTableRow(MyClass data) { this.data = data; }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass[] myObjects = new MyClass[9999];
        /* ... fill the myObjects array ... */

        MyTableRow[] myRows = new MyTableRow[myObjects.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.length; ++i) {
            myRows[i] = new MyTableRow(myObjects[i]);
        }

        /* ... show a JTable with myRows, and wait ... */

        for (int i = 0; i < myRows.length; ++i) {
            if (myRows[i].isChecked) {
                 /* ... do something with myRows[i].data ... */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to bind additional columns to existing objects in a `javax.swing.JTable`?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do. Personally, I'd create an object which represented a single row and which had getters (and possibly setters) which represented the columns.  I would then use an `AbstractTableModel` to access all this information

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ditto, except that I would probably explicitly extend `DefaultTableModel`, given we then only need to `@Override` several methods to make it work for a custom object.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm just a control freak and I usually already have my objects in some other structure ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"..just a control freak.."* A handy trait for a programmer. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson And knowing the right tool for the job as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how to bind your custom objects in table's cells?

If yes, the default data model of JTable is DefaultTableModel so you can cast JTable's model and using DefaultTableModel to work with table's rows. Please see the following links:

1. [How to use table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
2. [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: And I think that while this answer would make a great comment, I'm not sure if it actually makes the cut for 'an answer' as it stands.

Comment: @AndrewThompson JTable's API says that JTable(int numRows, int numColumns) will create JTable using DefaultTableModel. In JTable tutorial(the 1st link) it explicitly specifies "If the programmer does not provide a table model object, JTable automatically creates an instance of DefaultTableModel".

Comment: My bad..  Noise deleted.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, could you tell me when i should create an answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Do you mean how to bind your custom objects in table's cells?"* Should first be clarified in a comment, then *"If yes, the default data model.."* can become *"The default data model.."* (and the collection of words and links, an answer).  It would be good if the OP could clarify, so the question raised might be sorted.